# Need to add parentId to child in multi-dimensional Array of JSON data

Tags: javascript

I have a multidimensional array of JSON data with 'n' number of nested children. My task is to add UniqueId to parent JSON and that uniqueId should be added as parentId to the child. Can you please help in javascript. Thanks

Note:
The number of child its recursive, and there can be any number of children. For this purpose, we can have a deep level of three

Input :

```json
[{
    "text": 1527978678434,
    "value": 1527978678434,
    "children": [{
            "text": 1292232152442,
            "value": 1292232152442,
            "children": [{
                    "text": 474194771845,
                    "value": 474194771845,
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "text": 468086178830,
                    "value": 468086178830,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": 1067869237589,
            "value": 1067869237589,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "text": 1166591731429,
            "value": 1166591731429,
            "children": []
        },      
    ]
}]
```

The Required Output:

```json
[{
    "text": 1527978678434,
    "value": 1527978678434,
    "parentId": 0,
    "uniqueId": 1,
    "children": [{
            "text": 1292232152442,
            "value": 1292232152442,
            "parentId": 1,
            "uniqueId": 2,
            "children": [{
                    "text": 474194771845,
                    "value": 474194771845,
                    "parentId": 2,
                    "uniqueId": 3,
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "text": 468086178830,
                    "value": 468086178830,
                    "parentId": 2,
                    "uniqueId": 4,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": 1067869237589,
            "value": 1067869237589,
            "parentId": 1,
            "uniqueId": 5,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "text": 1166591731429,
            "value": 1166591731429,
            "parentId": 1,
            "uniqueId": 6,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "text": 111221786011,
            "value": 111221786011,
            "parentId": 1,
            "uniqueId": 7,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "text": 641372005975,
            "value": 641372005975,
            "parentId": 1,
            "uniqueId": 8,
            "children": [{
                "text": 23082640100,
                "value": 23082640100,
                "parentId": 8,
                "uniqueId": 9,
                "children": []
            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `data` is your array.
Just do the DFS and alter the data on the fly. + Having a global to hold the increased ID.

```js
let lastUniqueId = 0;
function addIds(children, parentId) {
    (children || []).forEach(r => {
        r.parentId = parentId;
        r.uniqueId = ++lastUniqueId;
        addIds(r.children, r.uniqueId);
    });
}

addIds(data, lastUniqueId);
```

Comment: Thanks @Han the soluion u gave is working perfect.. Thank you once again..

Answer (score 0):

This seems something you can do using a recursive function while keeping track of a shared `uniqueId` counter, assuming the nesting doesn't go incredibly deep:

```js
const data = [{
    "text": 1527978678434,
    "value": 1527978678434,
    "children": [{
        "text": 1292232152442,
        "value": 1292232152442,
        "children": [{
            "text": 474194771845,
            "value": 474194771845,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "text": 468086178830,
            "value": 468086178830,
            "children": []
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": 1067869237589,
        "value": 1067869237589,
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "text": 1166591731429,
        "value": 1166591731429,
        "children": []
    },
    ]
}];

function convert(array) {
    let uniqueId = 0;
    function mapData(data, parentId) {
        const myId = ++uniqueId;
        const result = {
            ...data, // copy all data
            uniqueId, parentId, // add our new fields
            // and handle the children recursively
            children: data.children.map(c => mapData(c, myId)),
        };
        // Don't mind this, just tricking JS in displaying the children array at the bottom during console.log
        const children = result.children; delete result.children; result.children = children;
        return result;
    }
    return array.map(d => mapData(d, 0));
}

const result = convert(data);
console.log(result);
```